# How to prove that this Markov chain is recurrent and irreducible?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose a Markov chain with $p_{ii+2}=\frac{3}{5}$ and $p_{ii-3}=\frac{2}{5}$, $i\in \mathbb{Z}$, then how to prove that this markov chain is  recurrent and irreducible?

---

I try to prove that $\sum p_{ii}^n=\infty$, but I can't calculate the $p_{ii}^n$.

Comment: You can calculate the $p_{ii}^n$. You are back to $i$ after $n$ steps if you make $2n/5$ steps to the left and $3n/5$ steps to the right. This way of writing it makes sense because it is impossible to do this in a number of steps that isn't a multiple of 5. So $p_{ii}^{5k}={5k \choose 2k} \left ( \frac{3}{5} \right )^{2k} \left ( \frac{2}{5} \right )^{3k}$. Does that actually help though?

Comment: @Ian From there, I think Stirling's approximation should be quite useful.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the 2 and 3, it should be ${5k \choose 2k} \left ( \frac{3}{5} \right )^{3k} \left ( \frac{2}{5} \right )^{2k}$ which is a much better situation (the thing I originally wrote is in fact summable, which is no real surprise because it actually corresponds to a random walk that drifts left!) Yes, from here Stirling gives the answer more or less immediately, you just have to be careful to lower-bound the $(5k)!$ and upper-bound the $(2k)!$ and $(3k)!$. You now have a rather familiar situation of examining $P(X=k)$ when $X$ is binomial($n,k/n$) distributed.

Comment: I totally got it ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @zhenyuboy If my answer is satisfactory I would ask that you accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return to $i$ after $n$ steps if $n$ is a multiple of $5$ and $2n/5$ steps were to the left and $3n/5$ steps were to the right. When $n=5k$, this occurs with probability ${5k \choose 2k} \left ( \frac{2}{5} \right )^{2k} \left ( \frac{3}{5} \right )^{3k}$. Now use Stirling's approximation to estimate the binomial coefficient, and you should find a non-summable lower bound for $p_{ii}^n$.